# Threads "disappear" in python 3.7 32 bit, but not 64 bit, unless I collect jobs and await them

Tags: python, python-3.x, 32bit-64bit

I am uploading a file via chunking in python, using `requests` for http requests, and `concurrent.futures` for threading. I have noticed some dissonant behavior between 32-bit, and 64-bit python 3.7, and wanted some clarification as to what I am doing incorrectly.

I am running on a Windows 10 computer.

Said dissonant behavior involves threaded execution concluding prematurely in 32 bit, but appropriately in 64 bit. This seems to occur whenever I have a relatively large number of threads (16), spread out over a relatively large number of chunks to upload (52)

Whenever I await my tasks in a somewhat oblique manner, I can get 64 and 32 bit to behave consistently. See code below.

Some functions I have defined

```
def read_specific_chunk(file_path, chunk_disposition, chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES):
    file_handle = open(file_path, 'rb')  # spawn new file handle for thread safe seek
    file_handle.seek(chunk_disposition * chunk_size)
    data = file_handle.read(chunk_size)
    file_handle.close()
    return data

def upload_chunk(chunk_position, file_transfer):
    file_chunk = read_specific_chunk(FILE_PATH,  # NOTE HOW THIS DEPENDS ON FILE PATH
                                     chunk_position)
    print("     Uploading chunk " + str(chunk_position + 1) + " of " + str(len(file_transfer.chunks)))
    place_chunk_url = CHUNK_PUT_URL.replace("#", str(file_transfer.fileTransferId)).replace("$", str(chunk_position))
    chunk_put_response = requests.put(url=place_chunk_url,
                                      data=file_chunk,
                                      headers=PUT_CHUNK_HEADERS,
                                      auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())

    if 200 <= chunk_put_response.status_code < 300:
        print("         PUT chunk " + str(chunk_position + 1) + " of " + str(
            len(file_transfer.chunks)) + " successfully for file transfer " + str(file_transfer.fileTransferId))
        return True

    print("         PUT " + str(chunk_position + 1) + " of " + str(len(file_transfer.chunks)) +
          " FAILED with status code " + str(chunk_put_response.status_code) + " for file transfer " + str(
        file_transfer.fileTransferId))
    return False
```

My problematic upload code

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
    for chunkPosition in range(0, len(fileTransfer.chunks)):
        executor.submit(upload_chunk, chunkPosition, fileTransfer)
```

My 64/32 consistently behaving upload code

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
    jobs = []
    results_done = []
    for chunkPosition in range(0, len(fileTransfer.chunks)):
        jobs.append(executor.submit(upload_chunk, chunkPosition, fileTransfer))
    for job in concurrent.futures.as_completed(jobs):
        # Read result from future
        result_done = job.result()
        # Append to the list of results
        results_done.append(result_done)
```

I expect each chunk to get uploaded  via the problematic code on both 32 and 64 bit python. However, it appears that some threads just aren't executed in 32 bit python. No visible error is thrown, either.